# C# MVC replace one Partial View with another

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm building a website using MVC where i want it to have a small box on the head Nav-bar where the user can log in to his account. The head Nav-bar is a layout page shared with all the views i have and the Partial view of the login is rendered in the layout.

this is the layout with the partial view placement:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            @Html.ActionLink("חנות השיגועים של האחים וויזלי", "Master", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("בית", "Master", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("אודות", "About", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("צור קשר", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("סל קניות", "Cart", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("פרופיל", "UserProfile", "Home")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("הרשמה", "Register", "Account")</li>

        </ul>
        @*<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>*@

                <div id="PartialPlace">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            @*</li>

        </ul>*@
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()

    <img src="~/Assets/Site_Background.jpg" alt="Weasly Shop" id="BkgImage" class="bg"/>

    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

this is the Login partial code:

```
<form method="post" id="LoginFloat" action="/account/login">

<div class="container">
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="UserName" required>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="Password" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

   @*@Ajax.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divToUpdate" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })*@

    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me

</div>
```

and this is the action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {

        using (AspStoreDBEntities1 db = new AspStoreDBEntities1())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var user in db.Users)
                {
                    if (user.UserName == UserName && user.Password == Password)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, true);
                        return PartialView("_LogedInPartial");
                    }
                }

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

What i want to do is when the user press the Login Button in the Login partial in the layout only the partialView will refresh and will show the user this partial view where he could post an ad:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron" id="LoginFloat">
    <h5>Hello @Model.UserName</h5>

    <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="">Advertise!</button>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="LogOff" value="LogOff" />LogOff
</div>
```

I tried using Ajax.Actionlink with the replacement action, but i couldn't figure out how to use it. Should i use it in the layout page or in the Login partialView or where?

Comment: It seems a pretty weak authentication IMHO....now, instead of `return PartialView("_LogedInPartial");` you need to return the other partial view...also in you ajax action link, you should change it with `UpdateTargetId = "PartialPlace"`

Comment: yeah the authentication is not bothering me right now.  In the controller i should return the other partial view: _LoginPartialView?  also, the Ajax.ActionLink should be in the _LoginPartialView and that will replace the partialView in the Layout page?

Comment: Ok, the `_LoginPartial` render the login form...now can you post the name of the other view?

Comment: The Last code section is the code of the other PartialView that i want to replace the first to. i called it: _LogedInPartial

Comment: So you just need to `return PartialView("_LogedInPartial");` form your controller method, and in your `AjaxOptions` place the  `UpdateTargetId = "PartialPlace"`, that should render-replace the login form with the advertise view.

Comment: the Ajax is in the _LoginPartial, in that partial i want a button click to trigger the switch. the place where i want the Partials to switch is in the Layout Page. so there is a problam with the procedure